# xCode 8.2.1 slow build objective-c with swift pod

Tags: objective-c, swift, xcode, build, cocoapods

The project with swift 'Socket.IO-Client-Swift' pod build time is about ~60 seconds, without 'Socket.IO-Client-Swift' it takes to build ~40 seconds. 
Is it impossible to speed up build process?

Answer (score 1):

Your build time is mostly dependent on the available RAM on your machine at that given moment, as well as if you are building on a device or a simulator. Simulators containerize themselves and are each allotted a small piece of RAM when they are in use.

If this build time is *truly* a problem for you, might want to look into resetting the content and settings in your simulator, deleting your derived data, or cleaning your build folder (although the first time you build again, it will be slower). These are surface level things that might help you see immediate time slices.

Additionally, it's worth noting that Objective-C has more files (`.h` & `.m`). However:

> Objective-C will compile progressively. That is, if you make a change
>   to one file, only that one file will be recompiled.
>
> Swift needs to recompile all files. Which does make it slower in real
>   life, because typically we are making small changes and recompiling.

Your question is a bit vague, but hope this helps in taking you somewhere with your issue

Comment: Your quote could use a source.

Answer (score 0):

Ok, I think i got it.

I just tried this:

[Xcode 8: Preparing Archive takes forever](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39934254/xcode-8-preparing-archive-takes-forever)

```
Open Keychain
Search for AppleID certificates
Delete all of them
```

I had ~30 com.apple.idms.appleid.* certificates. I removed them all and now it is taking about 30 seconds to build.